# Running mysqltuner on Mac OSX

Tags: mysql, macos, perl, mysqltuner

I use Zend Server CE on my Mac running OSX Snow Leopard for my development environment.  I need to tune up MySQL and have used mysqltuner.pl in the past on Linux servers to do pre- and post-testing.

I downloaded the script and get the following errors when I run it:

```
couldn't find diagnostic data in /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/pods/perldiag.pod /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0 /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0 . ./mysqltuuner.pl at /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/diagnostics.pm line 268, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
Compilation failed in require at ./mysqltuuner.pl line 42, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./mysqltuuner.pl line 42, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
```

Snow Leopard has perl and I have the XCode Development Tools installed.

It looks like I am missing some Perl modules.  I have tried to CPAN the files, but I'm not a Perl wonk and I think I might have screwed up my Perl install now.

Any ideas???

Comment: Sigh I so wish Apple would hurry up and ship perl5.10.1 already... 5.10.0 is so broken.

Comment: Report this as a bug to Apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something in there is using the diagnostics module, which requires the perl documentation to function correctly.  I'm guessing the perl documentation is a separately installable component from perl itself in OS X.

Comment: So the advice would be to find `use diagnostics` in the code and comment it out, then at least this hurdle will be overcome.

Comment: No, the advice would be to install the perl documentation.